# Custom prompts usint pyinputplus.inputMenu()

Tags: python, input

I am new here and new to python. (Currently learning from AutomateTheBoringStuff book).
In chapter 8 of the book: https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter8/, there is a practice project called **Sandwich Maker** right at the bottom of the webpage.

The goal is to create a program that asks the users what ingredients they would like in their sandwich.
In order to ask the users what type of bread they would like, I am using **inputMenu()** function from pyinputplus module as follow:

```
>>>import pyinputplus as pyip
>>>bread = pyip.inputMenu(['White', 'Brown', 'Sourdough'])
Please select one of the following:
* White
* Brown
* Sourdough
|
```

It works fine. Now I would like to customise the prompt: instead of having **"Please select one of the following:"**, I would like to ask **"What type of bread would you like?"** I am trying the following:

```
>>>breadCustom = pyip.inputMenu(['White', 'Brown', 'Sourdough'], prompt = 'What type of bread would you like?')
What type of bread would you like?|
```

Here is my problem: the **choices** given in the **first argument** of the function are not display to the user any more.

So next I am trying a different custom prompt:

```
breadCustom = pyip.inputMenu(['White','Brown','Sourdough'], prompt='What type of bread would you like ? \n* WHITE \n* BROWN \n* SOURDOUGH \n')
What type of bread would you like ? 
* WHITE 
* BROWN 
* SOURDOUGH 
|
```

Which works fine but seems a bit long and prone to mistake as what I have typed in the prompt value is not linked to the list passed to **choices**.

My question is: Is it possible to enter a custom prompt that solely replace the firt sentence of the default prompt: **"Please select one of the following:"** and display below the values in the list passed to **choices** ?

For info the help(pyip.inputMenu) returns:

```
inputMenu(choices, prompt='_default', default=None, blank=False, timeout=None, limit=None, strip=None, allowRegexes=None, blockRegexes=None, applyFunc=None, postValidateApplyFunc=None, numbered=False, lettered=False, caseSensitive=False)
    Prompts the user to enter one of the provided choices.
    Also displays a small menu with bulleted, numbered, or lettered options.
    Returns the selected choice as a string.
...
...
```

I noticed that the argument for **prompt** is **'_default'** **what does the single quote character around it mean**?

Many thanks in advance for your inputs.

Thomas

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are looking for something like that:

```
askForBread = pyip.inputMenu(
    ['wheat', 'white', 'spurdough'], 
    prompt="What type of bread would you like?\n",
    numbered=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually found away that answers my first question:
By storing the **choices** values in a list before calling the inputMenu() function and by referring to these in the prompt string.

```
>>>import pyinputplus as pyip

>>>l = ['White', 'Brown', 'Sourdough']

>>>bT = pyip.inputMenu(l, 
prompt = 'What type of bread would you like ?\n* %s \n* %s \n* %s \n' 
%(l[0], l[1], l[2]))
What type of bread would you like ?
* White 
* Brown 
* Sourdough 
|
```

With this syntax I will be able to change the values in the list (bread types) in the future without having to rewrite the code.

Comment: make sure you add "*" in prompt for each choice otherwise it will only display the choices as words without the prefix